# SQLite Counting Occurrences of Names from one Table against Name String in another Table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Ok after searching the internet, I can confidently say that I cannot find another post somewhere with this same problem, so let me explain what I am trying to do.

What I want to do is Select all names from the Members table and count how many times each one of those names appear in the string column in the Call table.

NOTE: The Members column in the Call table is a varchar that receives a concatenated string from my application.

```
      Member Table                  Call Table

FirstName     LastName              Members                       Officers
--------      --------              -------                       --------
John          Smith                 John Smith,John Smith2        John Smith
John          Smith2                John Smith,John Smith3        John Smith2
John          Smith3                John Smith2                   John Smith,John Smith3
John          Smith4                John Smith2,John Smith3       John Smith3
```

What I want:

```
FullName              nameCount
--------              ---------
John Smith                4
John Smith2               5
John Smith3               4
John Smith4               0
```

I haven't been very successful with approaches I have seen elsewhere. Any help would be great.

Comment: you say you can't find approaches elsewhere but then say you have not been successful with them.  This is a straight forward problem -- what did you do that did not work.

Comment: I have tried parsing out the Members column and then using a count, but haven't even been able to successfully parse them, since SQLite doesn't have Split, CharIndex, or Left.

Comment: These problems happen when you put multiple values in a single column instead of properly normalizing the data. Add a "call members" table with multiple rows per call.

Comment: This is what I am going to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be fast but you can join the tables using wild cards - like this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Member M
 JOIN Call C ON C.Members LIKE '%' ||M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName || '%'
```

This will give you all the locations in the call table for all the members.

Now just group by and count.

```
 SELECT M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName as FullName, COUNT(*) as nameCount
 FROM Member M
 JOIN Call C ON C.Members LIKE  '%' ||M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName || '%'
 GROUP BY M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName
```

Re-reading your question I not the 1, 2, 3 at the end of names.  Most data isn't like this but if yours is then you need to guard against it -- like this:

```
 SELECT M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName as FullName, COUNT(*) as nameCount
 FROM Member M
 JOIN Call C ON (C.Members LIKE '%' ||M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName || ',%')  OR
                (C.Members LIKE '% ' ||M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName)

 GROUP BY M.FirstName || ' ' || M.LastName
```

This only looks for names with a `,` after them or a space before them.

Comment: My bad on my part. My collection of Names does not include a space after the , after each name. With that being said, I changed it to a Left Join, so that I can get all 27 names from my Members table, instead of the 14 I was getting with the regular Join, and all the names show up, but they all have a Count of 1.

Ill show the updated query above.

Comment: did you expect them to have higher count?

Comment: This is working for some names, but there are are a few names that show up with less tallies than there should be. Also, I'm working on getting the Officers column included on this count and to also include Names in which who have 0 in Count.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 -- I don't believe you are using the same sql I posted and getting such results.  Please post the actual sql and at least one example column that is not working (being counted) and I will tell you why.